# Post navigation code

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I use this code for navigation in my front page:

```
<h13><div class="navigation">

<div class="next-posts">
    <div id="image_left"><?php next_posts_link('<img src="IMG URL"/>') ?></div>

    <div id="posts_left"><h12><?php next_posts_link('Older Stuff') ?></h12></div>
</div>

<div class="prev-posts">
    <div id="posts_right"><h12><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Stuff') ?></h12></div>

    <div id="image_right"><?php previous_posts_link('<img src="IMG URL"/>') ?></div>
</div>
```

I want the same navigation for my single post view but I can't get it to work, I made the changes for PHP functions but in Codex I only found a vay to display posts from the same category.
Also, I don't want the link to display previous/next post's title, only text that I define.
One last thing, I can't get the image navigation to work at all in single view, but it does work flawlessly in my home page.

This is my code at the moment:

```
<h13><div class="navigation">

<div class="next-post">
    <div id="img_left"><?php next_post_link('<img src="IMG URL"/>') ?></div>

    <div id="post_left"><h12><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post', TRUE); ?></h12></div>
</div>

<div class="prev-post">
    <div id="post_right"><h12><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous post', TRUE); ?></h12></div>

    <div id="img_right"><?php previous_post_link('<img src="IMG URL"/>') ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h13 and h12? I didn't know headers went up that high!

I'm guessing you already read the [Codex Page for the next_post_link() function.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) But did you make sure to include the call in the loop? Also, try adding in the extra parameters to the functions. Sometimes they get confused.

Comment: I used `h12/h13` so that I can control them more easily. I read the Codex on the topic but I can't get it to work without displaying the post title. It doesn't display the title only with the above code.

Comment: The problem with displaying images was that I really did have to add extra parameters so the image code is: `<?php previous_post_link('%link', '<img src="IMG URL"/>', FALSE) ?>` and the problem with displaying from the same category was that I didn't read CODEX on the matter of `true/false` parameter. Changing it to `FALSE` made the code perfect.